# How can I show a certain post recognised by title on my archive page? - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

So I basically have some sort of list with certain menu items, I want the top menu item to show on the archive page so it doesn't look empty. The post is always on top so I think the easiest way is to pick it out by the title of the post. But I have no idea how i can do this.

```
<?php

        $query = array (
            'post_type' => 'results',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $queryObject = new WP_Query($query);

        if ( $queryObject->have_posts() ): while ( $queryObject->have_posts() ): $queryObject->the_post(); ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This is my code basically and you can see that it posts the titles from all posts in links so that is is some sort of menu, on click it shows the content from the post.

Comment: Could you not just use a sticky post? See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: The post staying on top is not the problem, but displaying a certain post on the archive page is what i want basically.

Comment: Why don't you use tags?